# Add element to ts object

Tags: r

I have a ts object called A with 10 observations. I want to add 1 more at the start.

```
A[+1] <- 5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid R doesn't have such functionality yet, You''ll probably need to resort to `A <- c(5, A)`

Comment: Are you looking something like this? string <- "1234567890"
paste0("1", string)